# How to bind a subclass of an abstract class in a Spring-MVC method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, binding, controller, abstract-class

Given a "save" method in a Spring-MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save")
public void save(@ModelAttribute(MY_KEY) final MyModel myModel) { ... }
```

with a property in the `myModel` parameter that is an abstract class:

```
public class MyModel {
    public AbstractFruit fruit;
}
```

Is there any way of specifying use of a particular subclass (e.g. `Apple`) in the request?

Comment: Not easily. I think you'll have to write your own `PropertyEditor`. I don't think this is worth it. Just create different methods with different command objects for each type.

Comment: So you want/need to bind `Apple` (or another class) as the `AbstractFruit fruit` of your `MyModel` object reference?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes that's right

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, does that mean `AbstractFruit` would need to be taken out of the model and replaced with a property for each subclass?

Comment: Without knowing more about your domain, I think that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom init binder method in your controller class:

```
// Additionally using MY_KEY as "value" parameter of this annotation
// is not working in some cases
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

    // Probably you only want to init this when form is submitted
    if (!"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(httpServletRequest.getMethod()) {
        return;
    }

    // Filter out all request when we have nothing to do
    Object nonCastedTarget = webDataBinder.getTarget();
    if (nonCastedTarget == null || !(nonCastedTarget instanceof MyModel)) {
        return;
    }

    MyModel target = (MyModel) nonCastedTarget;
    if (/* some condition */) {
        target.setFruit(new Apple());
    } else {
        target.setFruit(new Banana());
    }
}
```

Spring form binding mechanism will then correctly set all fields in Apple/Banana class.