# Is there another way to instantiate a concrete instance of an abstract class inside a list during spring databind?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**Given the following classes:**

```
@Data @MappedSuperclass @Accessors(chain = true)
public abstract class EntidadeDeDominio {

    public EntidadeDeDominio() {
        type = getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @TableGenerator(name="entity_gen", initialValue = 1)
    private Long id = 0L;

    private String type;

}

@Data @Entity
public abstract class EntidadeAuditavel extends EntidadeDeDominio {

    @CreatedBy
    private String criadoPor;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date criadoEm;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modificadoPor;

    @LastModifiedDate @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class) @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'T'")
    private Date modificadoEm;

}

@Data @Entity @Accessors(chain = true)
public class OrdemDeVenda extends EntidadeAuditavel {

    private long numero;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="ordemDeVenda")
    private List<ItemVenda> itemVenda;

}

@Data @Entity
public abstract class ItemVenda extends EntidadeAuditavel {

    @ManyToOne
    private OrdemDeVenda ordemDeVenda;

    @OneToMany
    private List<DestinoItemVenda> destinoItemVenda;

}

@Data @Entity @Accessors(chain = true)
public class Equipamento extends ItemVenda {

    private long numero;
    private String modelo;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="equipamento")
    private List<Modulo> modulo;

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(numero);
    }
}

@Data @Entity
public class ProdutoGenerico extends ItemVenda {

    private String descricao;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Imposto> imposto;

    private double preco_unitario;

    public String toString() {
        return descricao;
    }
}
```

By being it's child, they all inherit a type attribute from the class `EntidadeDeDominio` and this attribute is also sent by the form by using a hidden field.

**And, to resume a little, some info about the form:**

Parameters received from the form when the object is an `ProdutoGenerico`

```
[id, type, numero, itemVenda[0].type, itemVenda[0].descricao]
```

Some of the parameters received from the form when the object is an `Equipamento`

```
[id, type, numero, itemVenda[0].type, itemVenda[0].modelo]
```

**And the problem:**

Spring, during DataBind (to a `@ModelAttribute OrdemDeVenda` object), fails to fill the `List<ItemVenda> itemVenda` because because `ItemVenda` is an abstract class.

**And the current workaround:**

After several seriously painful headaches and with the help of another post ([How to bind a subclass of an abstract class in a Spring-MVC method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531860/how-to-bind-a-subclass-of-an-abstract-class-in-a-spring-mvc-method)) I managed to get the following code to work (hardcoding the routine to use the 'type' attribute to instantiate the correct class and populate the list).

```
    @InitBinder
    public void registerConversionServices(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object nonCasted = binder.getTarget();
        if(nonCasted == null || !(nonCasted instanceof OrdemDeVenda)) {
            return;
        }
        OrdemDeVenda ov = (OrdemDeVenda) nonCasted;
        List<String> params = Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());
        long cnt = params.stream().filter(p -> p.contains("[")).map(p -> p.substring(0, p.indexOf("]") + 1)).distinct().count();
        if(cnt > 0) {
            List<String> types = params.stream().filter(p -> p.startsWith("itemVenda") && p.endsWith("type")).map(p -> request.getParameter(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                try {
                    Class<? extends ItemVenda> clz = (Class<? extends ItemVenda>) Class.forName(ItemVenda.class.getPackage().getName() + "." + types.get(i));
                    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ov.getItemVenda())) {
                        ov.setItemVenda(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    ov.getItemVenda().add(clz.newInstance());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**My question is:** Is there a cleanner way of achieving the same result? Like some sort of custom property editor?

**P.S.:** I tried very very hard to use some custom property editors but they were never invoked by spring. I tried stuff like 'registerCustomEditor(ItemVenda.class, myEditor), registerCustomEditor(List.class, myEditor), registerCustomEditor(List.class, 'itemVenda', myEditor), registerCustomEditor(ItemVenda.class, 'itemVenda', myEditor), ..., ... but none of them worked.

**Exception:**

```
Invalid property 'itemVenda[0]' of bean class [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.OrdemDeVenda]: Illegal attempt to get property 'itemVenda' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'itemVenda' of bean class [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.OrdemDeVenda]: Could not instantiate property type [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.ItemVenda] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.ItemVenda]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'itemVenda[0]' of bean class [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.OrdemDeVenda]: Illegal attempt to get property 'itemVenda' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'itemVenda' of bean class [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.OrdemDeVenda]: Could not instantiate property type [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.ItemVenda] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.ItemVenda]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Comment: have you tried implementing an interface for the two types and adding the interface to the list instead of the abstract class?

Comment: @Cwrwhaf when i do that I get almost the same error, but now related to java being unable to instantiate a interface:

`Could not instantiate property type [com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.IItemVenda] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.richard.weger.rerp.domain.IItemVenda.<init>()`